# Why are my sitelinks so weird and not being updated?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitelinks

I've done efforts to improve my sitelinks months ago, and they still make no sense. I've made sure I have the same header in all pages (~10mm) and that they are inside . Still I'm seeing a a sitelink to an alternate language version of the homepage es.klear.com (seen in the picture below as Inicio) and to a page (titled "For Business") that is not linked to from anywhere anymore (was replaced by a new page months ago). I've specified a couple of times for GWT to re-crawl my homepage, but still seeing the same results. (seen below an example for the full sitelinks when searching for klear.com, and for small ones when searching for just klear). This is the homepage: [Klear](http://klear.com)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Google generate sitelinks automatically, we have no more control on that, But we can use [sitelink tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitelinks) to Remove specific URL. So just remove/demote that URL, and let Google index other links.

Comment: @Goyllo While I get Google does it automatically, but it's based on the page we provide him. I'm asking how come my specific page has lead him to such conclusions (I might be doing something wrong) and if there's any way to make him update his decisions.

Comment: Do you use `link rel alternate hreflang` tags between your various languages?   Adding those tags might be enough to keep Google from seeing your other languages as important links for site links.  (Now I looked and I see that you use these links on your site already.)

Comment: Also, why is the description for "Inicio" in English?   If that is a Spanish page, shouldn't it have a Spanish description?   If you are using any English on your Spanish pages, that could be a big part of your problem.   When I look, it appears that your entire `es` site is actually in English!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your entire Spanish site (http://es.klear.com/) actually appears to be in English.   Google may include any important link it find on your home page into site links.   Because your Spanish site isn't actually written in Spanish, Google doesn't know that it isn't meant for English visitors.

[image: es klear]

Comment: In some (most) pages the navigation is in Spanish, and all these pages (including the one in your screenshot) has a link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" in his html. Doesn't that tell him?

Comment: In internal pages, you'll see more spanish, e.g. http://es.klear.com/profile/codinghorror . Also in the footer of the homepage. The page changed and I didn't add translations to the other parts... Do you think these semi english semi Spanish pages might be a problem?

Comment: Yes, semi English pages are at least part of this problem

Comment: Would you say it's best to avoid the language subdomains in my specific case in which pages are only semi-translated? (And 301 redirecting to the no-subdomain english version)

Comment: You should at least avoid linking to semi-translated pages.  Redirecting away from them might be a bit drastic.   If you were to do so, it would presumably temporary and you should use the 302 redirect.

Comment: My whole language specific subdomains are based on them being semi-translated, that's why following your comments I fell I might need to drop it all-together. In 2016, with Google's auto-translate options, is there really room for a website that has subdomains for semi-translated content? Am I causing more harm than good?

Comment: Semi translated content is not good for SEO.  It is against Google's webmaster guidelines.  You should prevent any such pages from getting indexed by search engines.

Comment: Can you show me the GWT guideline? When I've done it I took notes from here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en which states this as an option: `You keep the main content in a single language and translate only the template, such as the navigation and footer. Pages that feature user-generated content, like forums, typically do this.` which is what I've done (and ended up with semi-translated pages)

Comment: They have posted about it in their blog for webmasters.  Here is a good reference: http://climbtothestars.org/archives/2008/08/09/google-dont-mix-languages-on-the-same-page/

Comment: Your ES site has far more than just user generated content that isn't translated.   You have page titles, meta descriptions, navigation, and marketing language that isn't translated.   I would recommend not allowing search engines to crawl or index.  If it is user generated, it is likely to be duplicated from somewhere anyway.